# Encoding data in a DB column when it doesnt naturally 'fit'

Tags: database, normalization

Ive been tasked with normalising some DB data. 99% of it is fine, but Ive hit a quandry.

Its not my problem domain, but an analogous one is that of books. Imagine you have to record details of books, as well as how they're represented on vendor websites (perhaps for a price comparison engine)

Vendors A,B and C have each book represented by a single numerical identifier (though different for each vendor) Vendor D, however, starts each years releases at 1, so you need the year of publication as well.

If I only had to deal with A,B and C I'd have a master table of books, and a lookup table mapping my master book ID to vendor specific IDs. But vendor D breaks this. For example, I cant make vendorID,vendorCode a unique key, since for D, vendorcodes can be reused (code 1 will have a different entry for each year....)

One answer would be to make D's vendor codes a combined variable - so "123,2013" for id 123, year = 2013, and in my lookup code have something like:

```
if(vendor = D){
...split the code in two and format the search request accordingly...
}
```

But it seems a bit...hacky.

Am I missing some subtle trick of DB normalisation? Or do I just need to accept that the real world doesnt always normalise in a nice way?

Comment: Alternatively, you could also just append a year for vendors A, B and C, and split every item.  You just wouldn't need the extra data for A,B and C.

Comment: True. Im just wondering if theres some One True Way that doesnt involve any kind of kludgy hack.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is similar to something that's common in data warehouses and in legacy systems: mapping the primary keys from multiple systems. The two ends of the spectrum look like this. (It should be obvious that the *real* key for vendor D must include the year.)

```
One end of the spectrum
our_key  vendor_a  vendor_b  vendor_c  vendor_d_yr  vendor_d_num
--
1001     32        43        1856      2013         1
1002     143       887       2924      2013         2
```

That kind of table has (so far) five candidate keys.

- our_key
- vendor_a
- vendor_b
- vendor_c
- vendor_d_yr, vendor_d_num

Using a composite type for vendor "D" might make sense if your dbms supports composite, user-defined types.

```
The other end of the spectrum
our_key  vendor  vendor_key
--
1001     A       32        
1001     B       43
1001     C       1856
1001     D       2013-1
1002     A       143
1002     B       887
1002     C       2924
1002     D       2013-2
```

This table has a single candidate key: {our_key, vendor, vendor_key}. This end of the spectrum is essentially an EAV structure.

**Making the choice**

If it's practical, I prefer the first structure. It permits a high level of constraint checking. Each column can be (and often is) a different data type, and column-level constraints are easy to apply and to understand. You don't have to shoehorn compound types into a single column, and you don't have to parse that column in SELECT statements.

If you have to support an indeterminate number of vendors, though, it's not practical. Every dbms has either a hard limit or a soft limit on the number of columns you can declare in a base table.

But the EAV structure has drawbacks that might be show-stoppers, depending on your application. For example, it's trivial to guarantee that every value for "our_key" maps to a key from every vendors in the first structure. It's practically impossible to do that in the EAV structure.

EAV also requires you to shoehorn compound types into a single column, and to parse that column in SELECT statements.